# Linux: concatenate two substrings to a new line from infile read with cat

Tags: linux, cat

I have an infile with, let's say:

```
01;Masters;Robin;Atlanta;38
02;Jarau;Jennifer;Washington;29
03;Clavell;James;New York;78
...
```

I want to create an output which looks like this:

```
Robin Masters, 38
Jennifer Jarau, 29
James Clavell, 78
```

But I will NOT use the 'while read in; do ...; done' loop, because read is very, very slow for bigger files.

I would love to have a solution with 'cat', like this:

```
cat infile | echo $3" "$2", "$4 >> staff.list
```

(I have read that $0, $1, $2 are input parameters...)

Is there a solution with cat, maybe in combination with *awk* or *cut*?

Thank you in advance,

-Linuxfluesterer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s %s, %s\n", $3, $2, $5}' FS=\; infile
Robin Masters, 38
Jennifer Jarau, 29
James Clavell, 78
```

or

```
$ awk '{print $3, $2 ",", $5}' FS=\; infile
Robin Masters, 38
Jennifer Jarau, 29
James Clavell, 78
```

It's not as pretty with `sed`, but you can also do:

```
$ v='\([^;]*\)'
$ sed -e "s/$v;$v;$v;$v;$v/\3 \2, \5/" infile
Robin Masters, 38
Jennifer Jarau, 29
James Clavell, 78
```

There's certainly no need for `cat`.